# Is there any way of reading encrypted xlsx file via OpenXML lib?

Tags: openxml, xlsx, password-encryption

I need to read encrypted  xlsx file via OpenXML. Is there any ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a protected file in OpenXML.

You can identify a protected file with:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.protection?view=openxml-2.8.1